# Errata list for book 'Quick Clojure'?

Tags: clojure

Is there an errata list for the book 'Quick Clojure' by Mark McDonnell ?

I went to the publisher website and could not find one there : https://www.apress.com/gp/book/9781484229514

specifically i think there is an error in the following on page 50:

```clj
(defn add-n [n, coll]
  (lazy-seq (cons
              (+ n (first coll))
              (add-n n (rest coll)))))

(type (add-n (range)))
;; clojure.lang.LazySeq
(take 10 (add-n (range))) ;; <--- Error here: `add-n` requires 2 arguments ?
;; (5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14)
```

Comment: `add-n` requires 2 arguments, so the `(type...)` and `(take...)` both get an ArityException. Nonetheless, "where is the errata list?" might be a stretch for StackOverflow. What we need is for the author to come here asking "how do I fix it?"

Answer (score 0):

Let's see if we can't figure out what was meant. We know from the comment that

```
(take 10 (add-n (range)))
```

is meant to return `(5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14)`. It also appears that the missing argument is the `n`, which at first guess should be a number, and so the invocation of `add-n` should look something like

```
(add-n _ (range)))
```

So what value could we use to replace the `_` to make it return the expected value? The obvious answer is `5`. And so we test it by evaluating

```
(take 10 (add-n 5 (range)))
```

which returns

```
(5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14)
```

So there you have it. Now you can go to [the Apress errata page](https://www.apress.com/gp/services/errata) and submit this as a correction. (I can't because I don't own the book, don't know what page it's on, etc).